# IIS server problem please have a glance

Tags: iis

after deploying my web site to IIS
 server when i brows my web site kept
 under default web site it's displaying
 error message "You are not authorized
 to view this page"...please solve this
 issue

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you don't have the default document set correctly.  You may need to add `Default.aspx` to the list.

---

Other things to look at:

- That you're targetting .Net Framework 2.0
- That the permissions on the actual files on the server are adequate for the identity the website is running as
- That you have enabled anonymous access if you don't want Windows authentication

Comment: my iis server version is iis v5.1

Comment: help please rid me off from this issue .....help i am getting proper solution
it demands for user id and password as well...

Comment: @Novice - have added some more options